# argument isKindOfClass: [NSNumber class] - sane way to check this?

Tags: objective-c, types, nsnumber, objective-c-runtime, dynamic-typing

So I was playing with something where the class type of the arg is unknown until runtime.
like this:

```
- (NSNumber *)doWhatever:(id)arg
{
    // this ALWAYS FAILS
    if ([arg isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        return arg;
    }
    else {
        // what was it???
        NSLog("arg klass=%@", [arg class]);  // prints NSCFNumber
    }

    // This check works correctly.
    if ([arg isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (id x in arg) {
            NSNumber *result = [self doWhatever:x];
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)someMethod
{
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayFromObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], nil]];
    NSNumber *myNum = [self doWhatever:myArray];
    NSLog(@"myNum=%@", myNum);
}
```

This is obviously a contrived example of what I'm trying to do.
The point is this never works b/c the class of "arg" always appears as NSCFNumber, and I can't figure out a way to check for that.

Any way to make it less confusing to detect whether an arbitrary value in an array is an integer or not?

---

**UPDATE:**
Thanks @chuck, @omz, and @Nikita Leonov for your help.  What I posted here originally was just a simplification of the problem I was having and wrote it here without running it first.  That code once updated to remove the errors (see below) runs fine actually.

The mistake I made in my real code that I was having trouble with was equally silly--I was passing the array back in to "doWhatever" instead of the item at array's index, which is why I was having problems.

Thanks for trying to help, however misguided my question was.
Sorry for wasting everybody's time!

Corrected code that runs as desired:

```
- (NSNumber *)doWhatever:(id)arg
{
    // this NOW WORKS
    if ([arg isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        return arg;
    }
    else {
        // what was it???
        NSLog(@"arg klass=%@", [arg class]);  // prints NSCFNumber
    }
    
    // This check works correctly.
    if ([arg isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        for (id x in arg) {
            NSNumber *result = [self doWhatever:x];
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (void)someMethod
{
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
                        nil];
    NSNumber *myNum = [self doWhatever:myArray];
    NSLog(@"myNum=%@", myNum);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you build an array i such way? I wrote following code an isKindOfClass works well in this case:     
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
    if ([number isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSLog(@"NSNumebr");
    }

Comment: Checked initialization of array as shown in your "someMethod to os also works as expected for isKindOfClass call.

Comment: Did you really use this exact code? There is no `arrayFromObjects:` method, it's called `arrayWithObjects:`. Except for that, it should work and print `NSCFArray` (or something similar) instead of `NSCFNumber`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NSCFNumber is a subclass of NSNumber. As long as you're using `isKindOfClass:` rather than `isMemberOfClass:` or `[arg class] == [NSNumber class]`, it should work. If not, your problem is elsewhere.